# How to access a Self-Hosted SignalR server from a different machine

Tags: url, signalr, self-hosting

I have a self hosted SignalR server on one machine and I wish to access it from a client application on a different machine in the same local (in house) network). My client works fine using "Http://LocalHost:8089" on the same machine as the SignalR server. But I can't seem to be able to write a URL that will gain access from a different machine.

How can a client on one machine access the server on a different machine?

Comment: I've tried "Http://OtherMachine:8089" without success.
Nmap shows port 8089 open on OtherMachine
My SignalR server is running as a service

Comment: You probably have a firewall enabled, what OS are you running your SignalR server on?